# Go Folder Structure

Tags: go

I'm new to Go and folder structure and how source-files see each other is not quite clear to me. Here is a sample folder structure:

```
module 10x.dev/app

go 1.14
.
├── app
│   ├── controller
│   ├── model
│   └── view
│       └── cli.go
├── go.mod
└── tests
    ├── controller
    ├── model
    └── view
        └── test_cli.go

8 directories, 3 files
```

- How can this exact source code folder structure be made to work?
- With `cli.go` being the main source file and the application entry point, what will `go build` look like?
- How will `cli.go` see code in `controller`?
- How do packages factor in to all this?
- How will the code in `tests` see the code in `app`, so that `go test` just works?

If I got this to work, I (most probably many "we") would have a handle on this and climb up to the standard Go folder structure.

Comment: Please take the Tour of Go which explains packages better than we can here on SO and read How to Write Go code which explains modules and building programs in much detail. To your questions: 1. Having tests and code separated is a deadly sin and wrong in Go. So not at all, this layout is just plain wrong. 2. `go build` in that directory, dead simple as usual. 3. By importing its package like `import "10x.dev/app/app/controller" assuming you stick to the package-name==folder-name convention. 4. ??? 5. Not at all.

Comment: Timothy keep in mind that `go test` executes tests in files whose names end with `_test.go`, i.e. tests in a file like `test_cli.go` will *not* be executed.

Comment: You can do MVC in Go, but it's not usually the Go way. What's much more common is some variation of the [standard package layout](https://github.com/golang-standards/project-layout).

Comment: Let me add that MVC is _not_ about source code layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've really asked too many questions at once, for a SO post. And most of these questions are already answered thousands of times, with intro-to-Go types of documentation.

But your questions are individually fairly straight forward, so let me take a stab at it, one point at a time:

> - How can this exact source code folder structure be made to work?

Poorly. Very poorly.

The first problem is your structure of tests.  The Go tools look for tests in files named `*_test.go`. Putting your tests in another package can be done, but they still need to be called `*_test.go` (i.e. not `test_cli.go`) if you want them to use the standard tools.

You also lose the ability to access any unexported package-scoped symbols if your tests are not in the same package.

So, you *can* accomplish this aspect of your goal, but it will be *very* painful, and for no reason.

As for the entry-point of your program being `app/view/cli.go`, this is also very unconventional.  (Both in Go terms, and in MVC terms).  Your entry point must be in a package called `main`. There's no hard and fast rule preventing you from putting `main` in `app/view`, but that would be very unusual. What makes more sense is to put your `main` package either in the root of your project, or in `cmd/server` (or similar), and have that package access your M, V, and C components.

> - With cli.go being the main source file and the application entry point, what will go build look like?

If you insist on this, it would look like:

```sh
go build ./app/view
```

If you follow my advice instead, you'll have:

```sh
go build .
```

or

```sh
go build ./cmd/server
```

> - How will cli.go see code in controller?

Via an [`import` statement](https://tour.golang.org/basics/2), the same way it "sees" into any other package.

> - How do packages factor in to all this?

In Go, every directory is a package.

> - How will the code in tests see the code in app, so that go test just works?

It won't, using your "exact" structure, as explained above.

Learn to use the Go tools. Don't fight them. You'll be much happier.

Take a look at [standard project layout](https://github.com/golang-standards/project-layout) for one approach to Go layout that works well with the Go tools and ecosystem.  You can always adapt MVC to this if you want (perhaps create an `mvc` folder under `pkg` or next to `pkg`).